# Is there any runtime method to stop ld.so from searching default dirs? e.g. /lib, /usr/lib, RPATH

Tags: linux, linker, ld, shared-libraries

I'm looking for a way to disable **all** ld.so search directories so the only directories searched would be those in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Not re-linking or patching the binaries is preferred.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH have a priority above others. Isn't it enough?

Comment: I'm trying to write a script that runs a binary from a package (specifically dpkg) that can only load libraries from its dependencies. This is to ensure that the dependencies cover all loaded libraries.

Comment: I think chrooted environment would be easiest (while still being robust) solution.

Comment: You can always recompile ld.so. I believe the default version from the glibc website has no default search paths, leaving that up to the distro. Then compile with `-Wl,-dynamic-linker,/foo/bar/ld.so` or change the loader with `patchelf --set-interpreter` or invoke the loader manually `/foo/bar/ld.so ./program`.